# Create Nexus User Through REST API

Tags: nexus

I am working with Nexus OSS 2.11.x and would like to create new users through the REST API. The following command correctly retrieves the list of all users, thus confirming that I am able to call the API:

```
curl -u $NEXUS_USER:$NEXUS_PASS $NEXUS_LOCAL/service/local/users
```

Based on the API documentation, I've constructed a JSON user object:

```
export USER='{"data":{"email":"testing@example.com","firstName":"Test","lastName":"Ing","userId":"testing","status": "active","roles":["repository-any-read"],"password": "test123$"}}'
```

And then I submit a POST request:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "ContentType: application/json; charset=UTF-8" -v -d "$USER" -u $NEXUS_USER:$NEXUS_PASS $NEXUS_LOCAL/service/local/users
```

The response comes back with HTTP 201 (created) - but `GET /service/local/users` only gives me back the original user list. The user is not in the list provided from the UI, and the log (available in the UI) does not even indicate that any activity took place. The $NEXUS_USER account is in the "Nexus Administrator" role.

Does anyone have a suggestion for what I'm overlooking here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the above code and had the same problem:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
```

and nothing happened.
After some debuging I noticed a simple typo above which was a problem.
Instead:

```
-H "ContentType: application/json; charset=UTF-8"
```

should be:

```
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"
```

(notice the dash in `Content-Type`) and it started working.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't currently have access to a Nexus OSS server to try this out. You're clearly right that it should be `Content-Type` with a hyphen. What a dumb mistake! I probably entered it right "the next day" (post below) and never caught the difference.

Answer (score 0):

The code above is correct and executes just fine today. The server was rebooted overnight and somehow that fixed things.

To further clarify the environment variables

- **NEXUS_LOCAL** is your nexus server. If you install on localhost with the default settings, then `export NEXUS_LOCAL=http://localhost:8081/nexus` (Bash) or `SET NEXUS_LOCAL=http://localhost:8081/nexus` (Windows).
- **NEXUS_USER** and **NEXUS_PASS** are plaintext for an account with in the Administrator role, or presumably UI Administrator (have no tested the latter).